# When using yocto/bitbake, what's a correct way to install files in directories generated by a different recipe without conflicts?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In my system quite a few recipes are set to use monit and so need to install files in the `/etc/monit.d` directory - doing that by having

```
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/monit.d
install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/file_to_install.monit ${D}${sysconfdir}/monit.d/file_to_install.monit
```

in their `do_install()`. This however makes bitbake complain that "`file /etc/monit.d conflicts between attempted installs of`" my recipe and monit.

Monit is already set as a dependency of my recipe so I'd imagine that it would be taken as the one with higher priority, but it doesn't. What is the correct way to do this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to different permissions of those folders.
The monit_5.2 recipe uses permissions set to 700 .
Default install permissions when not using -m is 755

```
install -m 700 -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/monit.d
install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/file_to_install.monit ${D}${sysconfdir}/monit.d/file_to_install.monit
```